# Pegar o valor de um radio e imprimir ele JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto para meu tcc, preciso pegar o valo de um input radio e imprir o valor dele em um'card' interativo que fiz, esse card pega os valores digitado no input e imprime nele, porem não to conseguindo fazer com radio, eu ate consigo pegar o valor, por exemplo se voce selecionar 'cachorro' no cartao ira surgir a foto de um cachorro, porem tambem preciso que ele imprima 'cachorro' não sei se consegui explicar bem

o Codigo:

```
//cat
const $checkBoxPet = document.querySelector("#Cat");
$checkBoxPet.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if($checkBoxPet.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("imgP").src="img/catCard.gif";
  }
})


//dog
const $checkBoxPet2 = document.querySelector("#dog");
$checkBoxPet2.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if($checkBoxPet2.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("imgP").src="img/dogCard.gif";
  }
})

//other
const $checkBoxPet3 = document.querySelector("#otherPet");
$checkBoxPet3.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if($checkBoxPet3.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("imgP").src="img/bunnyCard.gif";
  }
})


**HTML**


                <div class="gender-inputs">
                            <div class="gender-title">
                                <h6>Raça</h6>
                            </div>      
                            <div class="gender-group">
                                <div class="gender-input">
                                    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="raca" class="ativo" checked>
                                    <label for="Cat" name="nameRaca">Gato</label>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                </div>
        
                                <div class="gender-input">
                                    <input type="radio" id="dog" name="raca" class="ativo" checked>
                                    <label for="dog" name="nameRaca">Cachorro</label>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                </div>

        
                                <div class="gender-input">
                                    <input type="radio" id="otherPet" name="raca" class="ativo" checked>
                                    <label for="otherPet"  name="nameRaca">Outros</label>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

**HTML Card**

        <div class="cardTwo ">
                      <div class="img">
                            <div class="form-card">
                                <div class="img-card">
                                    <img src="img/perfil.png" class="imgP" id="imgP" alt="perfil" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="img-card2">
                                    <img src="img/seloPet.png" class="img-selo" id="img-selo" >
                                </div>
                    
                                <div class="infor-card">

                                            <div class="cc-nameP">
                                                <div id="_nameP"class="value">Paçoca</div>
                                            </div>
                                                                                                
                                        <div class="cc-raca">       
                                            <div class="value" id="_racaP">Raça</div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="cc-cor">
                                            <div id="_cor"class="value">Amarelo</div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="cc-sexo">       
                                            <div class="value" id="_SexoP">xxxx</div>
                                        </div>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>



**Exemplo do que fiz com outros inputs**
**Java Script**

//validação nome pet
const namePet = document.querySelector("#namePet")
namePet.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const ccNameP = document.querySelector(".cc-nameP .value")
  ccNameP.innerText = namePet.value.length === 0 ? "Paçoca" : namePet.value

     //redimenciona o tamnhano da font do card
     ccNameP.style.fontSize = (ccNameP.innerText.length > 9) ? (ccNameP).style.fontSize="10px" : (ccNameP).style.fontSize = "15px";   
})

**Html**
                              <div class="input-wrap">
                                    <label for="namePet"> Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" minlength="4" id="namePet"  name="namePet" class="input-field" placeholder="Digite o nome" autocomplete="off" maxlength="16" required>
                                </div>
```

Comment: o código esta bem incomum, as váriaveis como por exemplo `const $checkBoxPet3` o sinal **$** é usual de Jquery, que não tem sintaxe de Jquery no teu código Js...

Comment: Não entendi, se é para digitar algo, pq está usando `radio`? De qualquer maneira, a ideia do `radio` é que somente uma opção esteja ativa por vez, então colocar todos como `checked` está errado. Sem contar que "raça" não é um bom nome pra esse campo (gatos e cachorros podem **ser de diferentes raças**, mas "gato" e "cachorro" **não são** raças, são tipos de animais). Enfim, se entendi bem, uma forma de fazer seria: https://jsfiddle.net/z0p59vfg/

Answer (score -3):

Bem provavelmete o metodo que estou usado para pegar os valores do radio não é o apropriado, creio que o correto seria fazer um switch ou algo do genero, mas como sou iniciante, passo um pano para mim kkk

dentro de cada if das const Checkbox adicionei um:

var ccRaca = document.querySelector(".cc-raca .value")
ccRaca.innerText = "Cachorro"

como eu ja consegui pegar o valor dos inputs radios, essa linha de codigo sobrepõe o valor do card com a escolha selecionada, pelo menos fez o que queria :,)

Comment: Saudações, nem " switch ou algo do genero" seus radios não tem `value` e todos estão marcados como `checked`.. Como poderia mostrar qual opção marcada ?.. o código que vós apresentou tem um uso bem peculiar. no entanto o código que apresentarei é bem simples o bastante para entender um entre varios uso do radio, espero que corrige alguns trecho no html e que esse exemplo simples ajude no teu tcc. https://codepen.io/cardosource/pen/jOKmBpm